# Why does the Normal Distribution have inflection points at +-1 standard deviations?

Tags: normal-distribution, central-limit-theorem, exponential-distribution

Supposedly this was [Laplace's first error curve](https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/upload_library/22/Allendoerfer/stahl96.pdf): [image: Laplace Error Curve]

Small errors occur more frequently, large errors less frequently; the shape of the Laplace Error Curve above roughly makes sense to me.

Looking at the Normal Distribution, I wonder about how we go from a negative quadratic (continuously differentiable, which is nice):
[image: Negative Quadratic]

to an exponential of that negative quadratic:
[image: PDF of Normal]

which has implications like these changes in the derivative of the Normal PDF:
[image: Derivative of Normal PDF]

What about nature says that the first standard deviation should be where the universal distribution of errors accelerates and decelerates?

Comment: History of probability from early 1800s is a bit murky, but I get the impression there were debates btw Laplace and adherents and Gauss and adherents about whose dist'n family was the best model for measurements of natural phenomena (e.g. in astronomy). It seems the normal dist'n won out, possibly not for the best reasons. Normal dist'n is often more tractable--and the CLT also helps tip the scales. // Seems N model is used out of habit when Laplace might be more useful. But L's steep decline in likelihood of near misses seems strange. // Not sure how this connects w/  $\mu \pm \sigma.$.

Comment: What probabilistic or statistical meaning do you perceive in the inflection points of a PDF?

Comment: Regarding the Normal specifically, how I read it is that the rate of small errors decreases dramatically until 1 standard deviation out from the mean, at which point the rate of errors increases. That switch of convexity is what I'm trying to grasp--why is it the case that it happens at +-1 $\sigma$?

@whuber

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by "rate of errors," but I can't find any interpretation in which what you write is correct.  The Normal pdf, like any pdf, represents rates by *areas,* so we're talking about the *third* derivative of that rate, not the rate itself, not its change, and not even its acceleration.

Comment: I think my last answer was written a bit strangely, apologies for the confusion. All I'm trying to say is that it looks to me like the probability of a large error decreases slower after 1 standard deviation and I'm trying to figure out why that is the case.

Does that make more sense than my last answer? If not, I might just be confused.

Comment: Might just be a statistical curiosity. See Dr. Simon's answer here: https://www.quora.com/Why-is-point-of-inflection-1-standard-deviation-away-from-the-mean-in-normal-distribution @whuber